# How do delete file uploaded by file_upload (FileUploadType) when entity is deleted?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

In a Symfony 3.3 entity managed with EasyAdmin 2.3.5, I have a property for a file to be uploaded.

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\QuestionRepository")
 */
class Question
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $video;

    // ...
}
```

I'm using the file_upload (FileUploadType) property in EasyAdmin form.

See https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html#file-upload

```yaml
# easy_admin.yaml

easy_admin:
    entities:
        Question:
            class: App\Entity\Question
            form:
                fields:
                    # ...
                    - property: video
                      type: file_upload
                      type_options: 
                        upload_dir: public%app.path.question_videos%
                        upload_filename: '[name].[extension]'
                        required: false
                    # ...
```

The file can be deleted with the cross icon in the edit form and then saving the entity. However when I delete the entity from the list view, the uploaded file is NOT deleted.

What am I missing ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you certain that the file isn't actually uploaded before the form submit, when you select it ?

Comment: @FTW The file does show up in the uploads folder when the form is submitted. Not before. But that's not the point. The point is that the file is not deleted when the entity is deleted by the delete action in the list view.

Comment: How does the click on the cross delete the file ? Is it your code ? Can we see it ?

Comment: The click on the cross triggers something in the processing of the form submit. It's coded in vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Form/Type/FileUploadType.php  where i can find a call to unlink() which is called from AdminControllerTrait.processUploadedFiles(). This is all EasyAdmin code. Nothing personnal.